# Laravel: Return a database query result using the MySQL SUM function and store it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I need assistance on how to return results from database queries using the MySQL `SUM()` function with Laravel. I know I need to use raw database queries and I've tried that but it seems to only return me an array.

**This is the code I have so far:**

```
$cron_jobs = DB::select('
      SELECT ROUND(SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time))/60)/15))
      AS cron_jobs
      FROM `quiet_periods`');

var_dump($cron_jobs);
exit;
```

**And this is my console log:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#689 (1) {
    [cron_jobs]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

The objective for me is to pull the value `20` from the returned result yet I can't seem to achieve this. When I run the following code:

```
echo $cron_jobs;
```

It should only show the value of the key / value pair.

*Please note:* I have also used `DB::statement` yet that returns the result of 1 which I am assuming is a Boolean result. I don't get why though... Oh, and I have used `DB::raw` within the `DB::select` but that only seems to return the same result.

Comment: Out of curiosity. What is the result of `var_dump($cron_jobs[0]->cron_jobs;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use standard accessors to get to your data

```
$crons = $cron_jobs[0]->cron_jobs;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Laravel version we are talking, but in 4 you got:

```
DB::selectOne($sql);
```